# Script that removes itself

Tags: multithreading, powershell

How to write a script that removes itself from hard drive. Let's assume following example what I want to achieve:

```
> dir
script.ps1
> powershell script.ps1
> dir   # <-- file do not exists
>
```

I am not familiar with power-shell, but I suppose it should look like below:

1. script creates a process that is waiting
2. script ends it's life
3. process removes the script.ps1 file from HD
4. process kills itself

The problem is that I don't know how to dynamically create a process that will wait for script to finish its job and then remove the file. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're way overthinking this. A PowerShell script isn't locked in any way while executing and any commands it launches will be children of the PowerShell process itself. A script is free to simply shoot itself in the head:

```
Remove-Item $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source
```

In fact, you can put a command after this and see that PowerShell will still run it because the script has already been loaded.

Comment: So simple? Can't believe that! I will check it on Monday and select the answer (I don't have windows on my PC). Thanks!